# Create an "IF" condition in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

I would like to create the following condition on Spotfire :

In english : if the actual date is empty for the last month, then fill in with "empty"

I tried with this but it doesn't work :

**if([Actual Date]= NULL, "empty")**

I receive this error message :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSvSa.png)

Thanks for the help :) !

Answer (score 0):

This would work if [Actual Date] is a String; it would create a new column that has the same value as [Actual Date] when this is not null:

```
if([Actual Date] is NULL, "empty",[Actual Date])
```

However if [Actual Date] were of type Date or DateTime this method would not work as you would replace a date with a string. So you could insert a special date instead - the value depending on your requirements to handle this date in further analysis

```
if([Actual Date] is NULL, Date(9999,01,01),[Actual Date])
```